# How do I convert the following from VB to C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm converting some code from VB to C#, everything is going pretty fine until the following lines related to XmlElements. This is the VB:

```
Dim headerElement As XmlElement = document.DocumentElement("ReplyHeader")
Dim errorMessage As String = headerElement.Attributes("errorMessage").Value
errorCode = headerElement.Attributes("returnCode").Value
```

And this is how I converted it into C#

```
XmlElement headerElement = document.DocumentElement("ReplayHeader");
string errorMessage = headerElement.Attributes("errorMessage").Value;
errorCode = headerElement.Attributes("returnCode").Value;
```

But I am getting errors like "Non-invocable member 'System.Xml.XmlDocument.DocumentElement' cannot be used like a method." and "System.Xml.XmlElement.Attributes is a 'property' but is used like a 'method'"

My issue really stems from not toatally understanding what the VB code is trying to do here. For instance, the first line, is it creating an XmlElement containing the text "ReplyHeader"? If so, how do I do this in C#?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you tried replacing () with [] ?

Comment: The first thing you should be doing is looking at the documentation, e.g. for [`XmlDocument.DocumentElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.documentelement(v=vs.110).aspx).  Open the VB file in Visual Studio, and make liberal use of the [F1] key.

Comment: Telerik have a great tool for this http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: @pho3nix thanks, I tried this but it only gave me what I have above. Looks like it is wrong too.

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic that did it! thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want brackets, in c# the pair of `()` denotes a FUNCTION call. To access elements you need to use bracket `[]` Indexers

```
XmlElement headerElement = document.DocumentElement["ReplayHeader"];
string errorMessage = headerElement.Attributes["errorMessage"].Value;
errorCode = headerElement.Attributes["returnCode"].Value;
```

Comment: Let me call it as `Indexers` this time?

Answer (score 2):

Lexical converters have trouble distinguishing VB's function calls from indexers, which use the same syntax in VB but different syntax in C#:

```
XmlElement headerElement = document.DocumentElement["ReplayHeader"];
string errorMessage = headerElement.Attributes["errorMessage"].Value;
errorCode = headerElement.Attributes["returnCode"].Value;
```